# Percentage of battery in Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: kubuntu, kde, battery

I use the task manager by default in Kubuntu 20.04 and i would like to see the battery percentage.
How to do that?
[image]

Comment: Configure Battery and Brightness Settings - Plasma

Comment: Then in General click Show Percentage . This will show percentage of battery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on the the white triangle left to your clock/time and left-click on `configure system tray`and choose always shown next to battery and brightness.